# Where can I find a spanish language copy of the rules of Settlers of Catan.

Tags: catan

I have found a link from a 2008 blog, but this fails now

Answer (score 2):

Would this would be of any use to you?

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/siedler/siedler_espanol.pdf

Failing that, this looks pretty thorough:

http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/30216/catan-todo-en-uno-reglas-y-mapas-para-todas-las-ve

Answer (score 2):

On [this link](http://wp.devir.es/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Catan-ManualDeLosColonos-Reglas.pdf) you can find the manual provided by Devir, the Spanish publisher.